# Simultaneous 2D scrolling in body of scaffold (design apps miro or figma)

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

I'm a newbie flutter developer

I need some guidance regarding 2D scrolling where I can put widgets in the body and scroll 2D (vertical, horizontal AND diagonal scrolling)

I do not require the actual code but guidance as to which widgets or the logic I'm supposed to use.

figma has 2d scrolling which is an exact example of what I want.

I'm sorry I don't have any initial code to provide as I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `InteractiveViewer` may be what you need:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('InteractiveViewer')),
        body: const MyStatelessWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatelessWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyStatelessWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: InteractiveViewer(
        boundaryMargin: const EdgeInsets.all(200),
        constrained: false,
        minScale: 0.1,
        maxScale: 2,
        child: Column(
          children: List.generate(100, (i) {
            return Row(
              children: List.generate(100, (j) {
                return Container(
                  width: 100,
                  height: 50,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all()),
                  child: Text('$i:$j'),
                );
              }),
            );
          }),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this!

This works perfectly with what i need.
Do all infinite scrollers use this or are there other methods to have an infinite 2d scroll?

Comment: @AkshayB I don't know if there are other methods but InteractiveViewer seems the easiest solution. Also see this Gallery demo:
https://gallery.flutter.dev/#/demo/2d-transformations

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SingleChildScrollView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleChildS) or [listView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html) for like static widgets.

if you have dynamic widgets than you can use [ListView.builder](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/lists/long-lists)

Comment: No, this doesn't work.

Comment: What I'm looking for is interactiveViewer widget but I don't know if it can add dynamic widgets